# Getting tags related to posts only from selected category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get tags related to posts only from selected category using `get_terms` or something. Is it possible?

Comment: Tags and categories are two separate entities. What I have understood is that you want to list all tags related to posts list appeared on specific category index page?

Comment: Yes, I meant that. But tags should be related ONLY to post from this category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not actually bound to category, but to posts and their IDs from that category. So you should be probably getting list of all post IDs in array from results of current query for category index page ( take a look at category.php, or archive.php template for the query loop) Example:

```
    $post_ids = array(); 
    while (have_posts()) : 
        the_post(); 
        $post_ids[] = get_the_ID(); 
    endwhile;
```

. And use that to call `wp_get_object_terms($post_ids, 'post_tag')`, to retrieve all post tags for given post ids from above.

It could be done building a custom db query with specific joins, which could be better for performance, but this is one way to do.

Comment: Looks right. I'll try this solution soon, thank you.

Comment: Exelent! Thanks again